# Shouldn't we consider duplicate paths in a cheapest first-graph search algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, a-star

Please watch this 16 second video demonstration of a decision made during the cheapest first search.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVCMMPXaQlE&feature=bf_prev&list=PL7D40B622BF0A97BC
At 00:08, the speaker chooses not to expand the path from Oradea to Sibiu since Sibiu has already been explored. I feel this is a wrong choice, because we are looking for the path with the least cost. Although Sibiu has already been explored, we still need to check this new path because it might potentially offer a path to Sibiu which is of lesser cost than the previously explored path to Sibiu. Please explain if I am right here or tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a duplicate decision you will get in a loop and never come out. That's why you keep visited nodes and never go back to them.